# How to make text fill in the gap created by an image (beside it) having a negative left margin?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, bootstrap-4

Basically, we must have this layout where in an image must spill out of the container and the text fills in the space created by the image (that is offset to the left).

[image]

We currently have this structure:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
       Some paragraph
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5 body-img-col">
        <div class="body-img-wrap">
            <img src="images/some-image.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-7">
        Some paragraph
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
       Some paragraph
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where `body-img-wrap img` is set to `margin-left: -100px;`. However, there's a gap that the image creates and the text won't fill it in as it's not in the same column. What we need is for the text to fill in the gap that the image creates when it's offset to the left.

How do we achieve this kind of layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution,

I divided the image and text into 2 section, Then I gave the width to the text-section equal to width of the image using

```
 width: calc(100% - 200px);
```

```css
.left-sec {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}

.right-sec {
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem error voluptas perspiciatis, possimus temporibus repudiandae facilis. Reiciendis eius eveniet voluptas est sapiente deserunt veritatis, eos earum et. Beatae, quae eaque.
      </div>

      <div class="row">

        <img class="left-sec" src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />


        <div class="right-sec">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime ab, quaerat. Necessitatibus adipisci doloremque optio aperiam placeat quis laudantium, quos quia iste hic qui rerum architecto quibusdam dolor? Perferendis, iure.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam, officia, consequatur. Commodi fugit, soluta tenetur cumque eum laboriosam unde, expedita nemo eos. Praesentium velit quam itaque vel harum sit odit.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I saw your original answer. Did you think the css shapes won't work?

Comment: @catandmouse, It can work, but I this was a much simpler method, and I refered your design instead of referring to the code

Comment: @catandmouse, If this answer helped you then please accept it